# Can Catalina backup an iPad automatically?

Tags: ipad, backup

I'm running Catalina on an iMac and have an iPhone and iPad both running 13.1.2  I'm using Finder to backup and sync the two devices and that seems to be working fine.  But... When I was backing up using iTunes the backups would take place automatically.  When I plugged in the device to the iMac it would open iTunes, backup and then sync the device.  Using Finder with Catalina I don't see a way to automate this process and I have to do it manually each time.  Am I overlooking a setting or is it not possible?

Correction: Finder is backing up my iphone automatically, but not the ipad although the settings are the same for both: Backup all of the data to the Mac & Encrypt local backup are both set to yes.